# When running in an OSGi container, what does it mean when a Class object's classloader is null?

Tags: xpath, osgi, classloader, apache-felix

I am having trouble getting XPath to work reliably in an OSGi context. When XPathFactory.newInstance is called, the following code is run (in javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory):

```
classLoader = XPathFactory.class.getClassLoader()
```

The classLoader resolves to null, which causes problems subsequently when the correct XPath implementation is looked up.

I am exporting the sun and com.sun packages to help with previous problems with XPath classloading where internal Sun classes couldn't be found:

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=sun.*,com.sun.*
```

I'm using Felix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The null classloader is the bootstrap classloader. Such a class was loaded from the bootstrap class path. This is true even when not using OSGi.